# How to compare exact same string but with different charCodes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, compare, string-comparison

I have the problem that the Sharepoint API returns me a string from a table that looks the exact same way as the string I want to compare it to. But the comparison is always failing.

```
at
"people lookbook+"
lt
"peo​ple lookboo​k+​​"
at == lt
false
at === lt
false
```

When I iterate through the strings and print out the charcodes then I can see the difference.

So how can I compare them or how should I decode this?

Here the charcodes:

```
for (index = 0; index < at.length; ++index) {
    console.log("char " + index + ": " + at.charCodeAt(index));
}
VM1116:2 char 0: 112
VM1116:2 char 1: 101
VM1116:2 char 2: 111
VM1116:2 char 3: 112
VM1116:2 char 4: 108
VM1116:2 char 5: 101
VM1116:2 char 6: 32
VM1116:2 char 7: 108
VM1116:2 char 8: 111
VM1116:2 char 9: 111
VM1116:2 char 10: 107
VM1116:2 char 11: 98
VM1116:2 char 12: 111
VM1116:2 char 13: 111
VM1116:2 char 14: 107
VM1116:2 char 15: 43

for (index = 0; index < lt.length; ++index) {
    console.log("char " + index + ": " + lt.charCodeAt(index));
}
VM1118:2 char 0: 112
VM1118:2 char 1: 101
VM1118:2 char 2: 111
VM1118:2 char 3: 8203
VM1118:2 char 4: 112
VM1118:2 char 5: 108
VM1118:2 char 6: 101
VM1118:2 char 7: 32
VM1118:2 char 8: 108
VM1118:2 char 9: 111
VM1118:2 char 10: 111
VM1118:2 char 11: 107
VM1118:2 char 12: 98
VM1118:2 char 13: 111
VM1118:2 char 14: 111
VM1118:2 char 15: 8203
VM1118:2 char 16: 107
VM1118:2 char 17: 43
VM1118:2 char 18: 8203
VM1118:2 char 19: 8203
```

Comment: You got a 'zero width space' (charCode 8203) there, just replace it with an empty string before comparing.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without regex. Maybe creating a dom element and read the text or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the help from Wa Kai and nomve I found out that there were those 8203 charcodes which I could get rid of by using following code:

```
lt.replace(/\u200B/g,'')
```

Just to make shure you can also use this:

```
lt.replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/g, '');
```

Which will remove:

- U+200B zero width space
- U+200C zero width non-joiner Unicode code point
- U+200D zero width joiner Unicode code point
- U+FEFF zero width no-break space Unicode code point

Answer (score 1):

8203 is [Zero width space](http://unicode-table.com/en/200B/). It is probably not really needed. You can strip it out like this

```
lt = lt.replace( /\u8203/g, '' );
```

The comparison will then work. The question is if some other characters get inserted in which case you would need to add other characters to the regex. Which might not be a very elegant solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not removing the 8203

Comment: Yes sorry, didn't have time to check... it is of course hex, and charCodeAt gives a decimal representation.